# Node.js handling successive asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a asynchronous function to create some user directories with node.js.

I would like the callback to be executed with a response containing the status of the operations for later processing. But the object is not being logged from within the for loop and the second mkdir. Also the subdirectory name is logged as the same thing even though all the directories are created correctly?

I have been looking for a while as how to solve this i think its due to closures and needs an IIFE? just i am totally lost now on how to solve it.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction please?

here is my code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var showSettings = {
  "userDirectories": ["shows", "uploads", "backups", "logs"],
  "showsFolder": "shows"
};

var Files = function() {};


Files.prototype.makeUserDirectories = (username, callback) => {
  let directory = (path.join(__dirname, "../users", username));
  let response = {};
  fs.mkdir(directory, err => {
    if (err) {
      response.status = "ERROR";
      response.error = err;
      console.log('failed to create directory', err);
    } else {
      console.log(`creating directory ${directory} succeeded`);
      let subdirectory = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < showSettings.userDirectories.length; i++) {
        subdirectory = (path.join(__dirname, "../users", username, showSettings.userDirectories[i]));
        fs.mkdir(subdirectory, err => {
          if (err) {
            response.status = "ERROR";
            response.error = err;
            console.log('error creating subdirectory', err);
          } else {
            response.status = "OK";
            console.log(`creating directory ${subdirectory} succeeded`);
          };

        });
      }
      console.log(response);
    }
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
      console.log(response);
      callback(response);
    }
  });
};

testFiles.makeUserDirectories("mr.test@somedomain.com", function(data) {
  console.log("in callback function");
  console.log(data);
});
```

My problem is that the returned response object to the callback is empty.
i think its something to do with the for loop and an IIFE but i am not entirely sure how to do this or if there is abetter way to achieve what i am trying to do?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try moving the  let subdirectory = ""; inside the for loop, if you want to create a blockscope then else block is not the place to declare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to execute your callback before your asynchronous operations have completed. Asynchronous operations can be very complicated, and there are many libraries to make things simpler, many based on the concept of Promises. These are objects that allow you to chain multiple operations together, with the cost of more overhead. I would highly recommend using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to produce a more intuitive function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var showSettings = {
    "userDirectories": ["shows", "uploads", "backups", "logs"],
    "showsFolder": "shows"
};

var Files = function() {};

function mkdir(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.mkdir(path, (err) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve("OK");
            }
        })
    });
}

Files.prototype.makeUserDirectories = (username, callback) => {
    let directory = (path.join(__dirname, "../users", username));

    return mkdir(directory).then(() => {
        console.log(`creating directory ${directory} succeeded`);
        let subdirectory = "";
        const operations = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < showSettings.userDirectories.length; i++) {
            subdirectory = (path.join(__dirname, "../users", username, showSettings.userDirectories[i]));
            operations.push(mkdir(subdirectory));
        }

        return Promise.all(operations);
    }).then((status) => { // this will not be called until all operations complete
        console.log({status});
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
            callback({status});
        }
    }).catch((error) => { // this will be called if an error is encountered at any point
        callback({status: 'ERROR', error});
    })
};

var testFiles = new Files();

testFiles.makeUserDirectories("mr.test@somedomain.com", function(data) {
    console.log("in callback function");
    console.log(data);
});
```

EDIT: Updated with a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Greg!  I hadn't even considered that as an issue as i have been trying to change my sync code to async. Promises are something i haven't used in anger yet.. I now understand the usefulness of them and will study them fully. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The code works perfectly btw!

Comment: You're welcome! Accepted answer would be much appreciated

Comment: Absolutely! This really is a nice bit of code, thanks! i would have been unable to figure this out without your help as I was looking in the wrong direction. Perhaps someone can change the title to something more relevant to make it more useful for others to find this answer? thanks